# work done using line integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vectors

Question :

How much work is done in pulling an object constrained to move along the portion of the curve y = $x^2$; z = $x^3$ from (0; 0; 0) to (1; 1; 1) (positions in meters), if the rope pulling it is always in the direction < 1;-3;-4 > and the tension in the rope is constant at 100 Newtons?

Attempt:

the magnitude of F is 100 Newtons to find its vecor form, do i have to find the unit vector of <1,-3,-4>? r(t) = ti + $t^2$j + $t^3$k and 0 < t < 1?

is that correct?

Comment: You could take a more easier route, hint:as the direction and force of rope is constant, it is just like gravity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your form for $\vec r(t)$ is correct.

To get the vector for $\vec F$, you can write it $$ \vec F = F\langle 1,-3,-4\rangle$$ where $F$ is a scalar (that way it goes in the right direction). And then you know its magnitude is $100$ Newtons, so to find $F$ you set $|\vec F| = 100$ and solve.

Then take $\vec F\cdot \vec r'(t)$ and integrate from $t=0$ to $t=1$ to find the work.

Comment: Math Lover deserves the check-mark. I got it in later and more importantly my last line was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to compute the unit vector along $\langle 1,3,-4 \rangle$. All you need is to compute the force vector along this vector. In particular, $$\vec F = c(\mathbf{i}+3\mathbf{j}-4\mathbf{k}),$$ where $|\vec F|=100 \implies c = 100/\sqrt{1^2+3^2+4^2}$. After computing $\vec F$, obtain the work, $W$, by $$W = \int \vec F \vec{\cdot d r}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You could take a more easier route

> As the magnitude and direction of the force of constant it is just like gravitational pull.

So you could easily learn from the potential energy equation of gravity *$mgh$*

For your variable like *$h$* , consider the component of displacement in the direction of force.